# Does IBM Java 6 need jaxb jars for Session Preview?

Tags: experience-manager

We are configuring Session Preview and are getting the infamous recurring "The preview for this page is not up to date" message.

We are using IBM Java 6 on our webapp, and the installation steps state (http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/UIU4SDLT2011SP1/task_01C70C0987914EE786D4033424ED8FA5):

> If you use Java 1.5 or IBM Java, access the 1.5\ subdirectory and
>   also copy the files you find there to WEB-INF/lib/:  jaxb-api.jar, 
>   jaxb-impl.jar

The way I interpret the above is: if I am on regular Oracle Java 1.5 or *any* version of IBM Java then I need those jaxb jars.  Would you please confirm if this is the correct way to interpret the statement, or if those jars are only needed for IBM Java 5 and Oracle Java 1.5?

Also, despite the correctness/incorrectness of the statement, would you please confirm if we actually need those jaxb jars for IBM Java 6?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Java SE 6 implementation is required to include the standard JAXB (JSR-222) APIs as well as an implementation of JAXB that passes all the required TCKs.

A Java SE implementation prior to version 6 would not have these jars and require you to add them to the classpath yourself.

---

**UPDATE**

> Thank you. So are you saying that for IBM Java 6 we do not need to
>   include these jars because they must be present as per JSR-222?

I'll try to clarify:

1. You would not need to include the `jaxb-api.jar` jar in a Java SE 6 implementation.
2. If Session Preview is JAXB implementation agnostic then you will not need to include `jaxb-impl.jar` on the class path as Java SE 6 implementations already contain a JAXB implementation.  If Session Preview is not JAXB implementation agnostic then you will need to include this jar (you could always include it to be safe).

Comment: Thank you. So are you saying that for IBM Java 6 we do not need to include these jars because they must be present as per JSR-222?